# ScaleAnimation Large to Small

Tags: android, animation, scaleanimation

So the following animation works as expected:

```
Animation scaleUp = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    scaleUp.setDuration(1000);
```

Sadly, this one doesn't:

```
Animation scaleDown = new ScaleAnimation(2, 1, 2, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    scaleUp.setDuration(2000);
```

The view that has the scaleDown animation simply waits 2 seconds then suddenly appears. I can't figure out why scaleUp works but scaleDown doesn't.

Scale animation DOES work with fromX and fromY values greater than 1 correct? I couldn't find any documentation to say otherwise.

Comment: To clarify, I want the object to temporarily appear LARGER than it really is, then grow smaller to it's actual size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is that , your have set the scale down duration to **scaleUp** and not **scaleDown**.

change it as below..

```
Animation scaleDown = new ScaleAnimation(2, 1, 2, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
scaleDown.setDuration(2000);
imageView.setAnimation(scaleDown);
```